# MS Access and QSqlQuery

Tags: qt

My english is not very good but i’ll try to describe my problem.
 So, i have primitive code:

```
    base = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

 QSettings sets("FlowModel","Settings");

 currentBase = sets.value("currentBase").toString();

    base.setHostName("localhost");

    base.setDatabaseName(QString("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=%1").arg(currentBase));

 if(base.open())

  QMessageBox::information(0,"Все отлично!","База данных открыта","Ок");

 else

  QMessageBox::information(0,"Все не ахти!",base.lastError().text(),"Ок");



 QSqlQuery queryMaterials("SELECT * FROM Материал",base);

 int fieldNo = queryMaterials.record().indexOf("Название");

 int i = 0;

 while (queryMaterials.next()) {   

  comboBox->insertItem(i++,queryMaterials.value(fieldNo).toString());

     }

 queryMaterials.clear();
```

It works correctly and combo box takes all materials from Database;
But next is going this code:

```
QSqlQuery queryInfo("SELECT * FROM Свойства_материала WHERE Название='Вода'",base);

fieldNo = queryInfo.record().indexOf("P");

pLine->setText(queryInfo.value(fieldNo).toString());
```

And it didn’t work! Query returns an empty string (”“), but must be a number. I test this SQL-query in Access and there it works correct. Please help to understand what a problem i have.
Thank you.
P.S. I’m tried to use QSqlQuery::lastError().text() method, but it report me nothing.
I can’t understand what is that… Because this table can be opened by this code:

```
QSqlDatabase accessBase = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

 accessBase.setHostName("localhost");

 accessBase.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=D:/ИТ.mdb");

 if(accessBase.open())

  QMessageBox::information(0,"Все отлично!","База данных открыта","Ок");

 else

  QMessageBox::information(0,"Все не ахти!",accessBase.lastError().text(),"Ок");

 QTableView tableGhost;

 QSqlTableModel tableDB;

 QString whtpn = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Какую таблицу открыть?",

   "Какую таблицу открыть?");

 tableDB.setTable(whtpn);

 tableDB.select();

 tableDB.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
 tableGhost.setModel(&tableDB);

tableGhost.show();
```

And all ok. But by query no(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved.
Before line 
pLine->setText(queryInfo.value(fieldNo).toString());
Had to use method QSqlQuery::next();